# Making the Ctrl+C (Ctrl+V, Ctrl+Z, Ctrl+X) keyboard shortcut one button press in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I'm doing a large amount of tedious copying and pasting from a text file into some database seed code. Hand is getting sore.

I want to do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> in one button press instead of stretching my hand between these two keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tools, options, keyboard, can change hotkeys from there. e.g. I made <kbd>F1</kbd> copy and <kbd>F2</kbd> paste.